# Ladies’ Captain or Ladies Captain?

Tags: apostrophe

I write a newsletter for our Golf Club. Should I sign it off as Sue. Ladies’ Captain. Or Sue. Ladies Captain. ??

Comment: How does the club usually write the title for the captain of the ladies?

Answer (score 1):

*Ladies Captain* would be consistent with common usage, since this term is jargon in the field. Many examples are available, such as:

> Ladies Captain means the Captain responsible for Ladies Golf elected to represent the Lady Members at Club and County level and to fulfil [sic] any requirements of the relevant Golf Association.

[Law Insider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/ladies-captain)